# fields could not be resloved, while it's obviously there! (implementing a map.h)

Tags: c++, eclipse, dictionary

I am writing a generic code in C++ of a map data structure.
it's supposed to be based on a linked list, so actually i like to think of it as a linked list with 2 entries instead of one.
So first, i have the following (template) classes:
const_iterator, iterator, Map, Node.

The classes that are relevant to the question are the map (the main class that uses all the rest) and Node. this is how they defined:

```
template<class K, class T>
class Map {
    class Node;
    Node* head;
    Node* first;
    Node* firstDemoNode;
    Node* lastDemoNode;
    int sizeOfMap;
    Node* searchAux(K& key);
```

Of course, those are just the fields, I did not include the methods.
and the Node class:

```
template<class K, class T>
class Map<K, T>::Node {
       friend class Map<K, T> ;
       T data;
   K key;
   Node* prev;
   Node* next;
   bool isDemo;
   friend class const_iterator;
}
```

and last class, const_iterator:

```
class Map<K, T>::const_iterator {
friend class Map<K, T> ;
const Map<K, T>::Node* node;
const Map<K, T>* map;
```

the problem is very weird. some of the methods of const_iterator that use the Node class, do not recognize the node class when i try to use it, i.e when I implement a method like:

```
const T& getData() {
        return node->data;
    }
```

the compiler (eclipse, g++) tells me "Field 'data' could not be resloved
the same goes for:

```
const K& getKey() {
    return node->key;
}

typename Map<K, T>::const_iterator& operator++() {
    if (node != NULL) {
        node = node->prev;
    }
    return *this;
}
typename Map<K, T>::const_iterator& operator--() {
    if (node != NULL) {
        node = node->next;
    }
    return *this;
}
```

whe the field that could not be resolved is the one that comes after the node->

I would appreciate any help and I'm sorry fot the long post.
Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: "the compiler (eclipse, g++) " it seems there is a confusion there, eclipse is the ide, g++ is the compiler. Who tells you that? It sounds to me that it is eclipse. Have you tried compiling?

Comment: I think that some `typename` are missing.

Comment: Can't reproduce: http://ideone.com/nJCw44. Could you post a complete example, and the exact error message? Or is this just Eclipse failing to index the code (as it often does), rather than a compile error?

Comment: @Jarod42: That would be needed to use dependent type names, but these errors apparently come from dependent data member names, which don't need any qualification.

Comment: I can confirm that the Eclipse code analysis complains, but compiling with g++ is no problem.

Comment: ok sorry for the bad definition of eclipse/g++.
I'm coding in Eclipse.
@MikeSeymour, would you like me to post the whole code? is that ant better:
http://ideone.com/Fa4tiA?

Comment: @wannabeprogrammer: A small amount of code that reproduces the error would be ideal. That's a lot of code, and doesn't reproduce it, even if I add a `main()` to instantiate the problematic member functions. Again, are you sure this is a genuine compiler error, not just Eclipse showing spurious errors?

Answer (score 0):

From the snippets of code you posted I generated the following test case in Eclipse (also removed some stuff that is unnecessary):

```
template<class K, class T>
class Map {
    class Node;
    class const_iterator;
};

template<class K, class T>
class Map<K, T>::Node {
   friend class Map<K, T> ;
   friend class const_iterator;
   T data;
};

template<class K, class T>
class Map<K, T>::const_iterator {
    friend class Map<K, T>;
    const Map<K, T>::Node* node;
    const T& getData() { return node->data; }
};

int main() {
    Map<int, int> test;
}
```

This compiles fine, except for a warning that `test` is unused, but this doesn't matter here.

However Eclipse still (even after compilation) shows a code analysis error for the line `const T& getData() { return node->data; }`:

```
Field 'data' could not be resolved
```

This is **not** an actual error, it is rather a notification, that the code analyzer could not resolve the name in the live analysis. You can safely ignore this warning. These code analysis errors are marked with red or yellow bugs, while compiler errors (which are far more relevant) are marked with red crosses. The static code analysis is supposed to help you find (semantic) mistakes while you are writing code, but it is not perfect and my have false positives.

In this case the type of `node` is not known until instantiation at compilation, so the fields are unknown to the analyzer. (Although I feel like the analysis should be sophisticated enough to determine the possible types here or at least identify it as incomplete, therefore not showing any error.)

You can configure whether/how these errors are shown in `Window -> Preferences -> C/C++ -> Code Analysis`. You can exclude complete files there from being scanned, but I am not aware of a method to disable a particular error message on one line.